# Determining "trial" solution for particular integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the DE $x^2y''+xy'-4y=15x^3$, supposedly the particular integral can be found by attempting $y=Cx^3$ and then substituting. However it's not clear to me why this is. I would have thought the most logical starting point would be an arbitrary polynomial of degree $3$, i.e. $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$. How does one know that the true solution will only be of the form $Cx^3$?

Comment: Will $A$ have a chance at influencing $B$? Are any of $A,B,C,D$ coupled after inserting the full polynomial?

Comment: May I confess that I would have done the same as you ?